# Microsoft Access - Dlookup with multiple criteria from different tables

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-office

I have 2 tables in my DB. One called Manufacture and the other Product.

The Manufacture table has 2 fields:

- Number
- Name

The Product table has 3 fields:

- Number
- Name
- Manufacture_Number

What I want is When I create a new product, it shows me if the product already exists. I'm currently using this code:

```
DLookup("[Name]", "Product", "[Name] = '" & me.txtName.value & "'")
```

It works just fine, but once happened that a product with the same name but different manufacture. I could not create a record because of that.

I only could not create a new record if the is the same product and the same manufacture as already created.

How do I create one Dlookup for multiple criteria in different tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you don't really want to look across different tables. You want to prevent adding a product with the same name and manufacturer as an existing product, so you want to check both fields in the `Product` table:

```
DLookup("[Name]", "[Product]", "[Name] = '" & me.txtName & "' And Manufacture_Number = " & me.txtMfrNumber)
```

It's more likely that your input control for the manufacturer is going to be a combo box, but that works too - just replace `txtMfrNumber` with the name of the control that you're using to get this number.

Note that you don't need to specify the `.Value` on the end of `me.txtName` as `Value` is the default property of your text box.

Answer (score 1):

You have to nest the `DLookups` like this:

```
DLookup("[Name]","Product","[Name]='" & me.txtName.value & "' AND Manufacture_Number=" & Nz(DLookup("Number","Manufacture","[Name]='" & me.txtManufactureName.value & "'" ,0)))
```

I am using `Nz` to avoid errors when`DLookup` returns null.