# DLookup to return prices

Tags: ms-access

Good afternoon all,

I am in the process of creating a database in which I want to enter a product name and a dose and a price will be returned. I have created two tables (tbllog and tblcosting). The tblcosting contains the products along with all the available doses and the prices they cost. Is there a way of inputting the product and dose onto one form and having a box that returns the price based on these two criteria?

Any advice you could pass on would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You can indeed use the DLookup function. Check this link on how to use multiple criteria https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377952/microsoft-access-dlookup-with-multiple-criteria-from-different-tables

Answer (score 1):

Select product from a combobox. Make the combobox RowSource multi-column:

`SELECT ProductID, ProductName, Dose, Cost FROM tblCosting ORDER BY ProductName;`

Have textboxes reference the combobox columns by index to display the associated info. Index begins with 0 so Cost is in column index 3:

`=[cbxProduct].Column(3)`

Comment: Thanks for this, I have done something similar before and not too sure I asked the question clear enough. I would like to be able to enter the product in one box and enter the dose in a separate box on the form and the program to match these two up to give me a price. I have drafted something on Excel using VLOOKUP which does this. Would it help explain my dilemma if I posted this?